# Why does System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImage require an unused delegate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This blows my mind.  Why does this method require an unused argument?  Also, it requires an IntPtr that "Must be Zero."  This seems to be entirely pointless.  Can anyone explain?

Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for earlier version, like [GetThumbnailImage in framework 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it says:

> "In GDI+ version 1.0, the delegate is not used."

The parameters are remains from an early version, and the method signature hasn't changed.

Comment: You'd think they could swing back around someday in a newer version of the .Net GDI+ wrapper and write another overload without those parameters, or at least make them optional.

Comment: @DustinRasener: I think it's more that they left it unchanged to keep from adding overloads to a method that isn't used very often anyway. There are many overloads that could be added to many methods in the framework, but we all want the framwork download size kept to a minimum.

Comment: @Guffa: That sounds more like post hoc justification than a considered reason for not adding the overload.

Comment: @DustinRasener: I don't have any specific knowledge about the process around this method, but I know that a lot of changes are considered for each new framework version, and that some are rejected or posponed because they don't give enough benefit to justify the work involved in doing the change, mostly all the testing that each change requires. You can submit a request for another overload at the MSDN page for the method if you like.